# Disabling mirror option in preseed.cfg

Tags: debian, mirror, preseed

I am installing Debain Weezy (netinstall) in VirtualBOX using `preseed.cfg`.

I'm trying to create a `preseed.cfg` that would skip/not set Debian mirror in the `Configure the package manager` step. I am not installing any additonal packages (`tasksel tasksel/first multiselect none`) therefore "a very minimal base system"

If I use `d-i mirror/country string manual` I get

```
Please enter the hostname of the mirror from which Debian will be downloaded
```

I then have to manually select `Go back` and select `Yes` when asked `Continue without a network mirror?`.

Setting `d-i mirror/country string boolean false` gives the same dialogue.

Additionally something like `d-i mirror/confirm boolean true` needs to be added too I think since it's a two-step dialogue.

Comment: the solution for this problens is on the link http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216348/debian-disabling-use-mirror-on-preseed-cfg

Answer (score 3):

I ran the installer without picking a mirror. In the resulting system, all installer options used can be found at `/var/log/installer/cdebconf/questions.dat`

search mirror related params in this file. mine shows

> Name: apt-setup/no_mirror
>   Template: apt-setup/no_mirror
>   Value: true
>   Owner: apt-mirror-setup

thus the preseeding setting should be

```
d-i apt-setup/no_mirror boolean true
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the settings of all the keys to `none` for it to work. Try this:

```
d-i mirror/country string manual
d-i mirror/http/hostname string ""
d-i mirror/http/directory string ""
d-i mirror/http/proxy string ""
```

This tells the installer, set the mirror in manual, the hostname is none, the directory is none, and the proxy is none.

Comment: This sadly doesn't work either: "Bad archive mirror"