# Debian - disabling use mirror on preseed.cfg

Tags: debian, debian-installer

I have created a preseed automated installation on my Debian jessie 8, but after installing the base packages, it returns error message error it can not use the

> mirror package, please enter hostname another mirror...

But if I select the option to ignore it continues, is there any way to do this automatically via a preseed file?

Answer (score 2):

Comment all the lines referring to `apt-setup`, and add

```
d-i apt-setup/use_mirror boolean false
```

You also need to define a mirror, with something like the following, or will *always* be prompted for one:

```
d-i mirror/country string manual
d-i mirror/http/hostname string archive.ubuntu.com
d-i mirror/http/directory string /ubuntu/
d-i mirror/http/proxy string
```

There is no combination of other options that will bypass the mirror dialog without choosing a mirror. I've tried hundreds of combinations without luck.

You either choose a mirror and define it statically, or you will be prompted.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in the `preseed.cfg`:

```
d-i apt-setup/no_mirror boolean true
```

Comment: my preseed.cfg http://pastebin.com/4jMDim3M i have add line on the file, put the error persist,

Comment: i have comented all line referente apt-setup and added this line d-i apt-setup/use_mirror boolean false all errors have gone...

Answer (score 1):

To disable mirrors, the only lines considering mirrors should be:

```
d-i apt-setup/use_mirror boolean false
```

And if you also don't want any updates (like security.debian.org), because You will configure those differently after installation and don't want to be interrupted during it if the network is down e.g. use:

```
d-i apt-setup/services-select multiselect
```

(without the default `security, updates`)

Of course you should use a DVD or CD for installation then. To prevent being bothered with dialogue to scan other DVDs, add:

```
d-i apt-setup/cdrom/set-first boolean false
```

This should do the trick.